# Upper bound for $P(\sum_{1}^{20} X_i>15)$ with $X_i\thicksim Poisson(1)$

Tags: probability, upper-lower-bounds

I have this question

> Let $X_i\thicksim Poisson(1)$ identical independant random variables. Obtain an upper bound for $P(\sum_1^{20}X_i>15)$ without using the Central Limit Theorem.

Using it I saw the upper bound should be $0.025$, but I don't know another method to obtain an upper bound. Could anyone give me a hint to obtain it?

Comment: This probability is close to $1$. Sure this is your question?

Comment: Yes, I need to obtain the probability that $P(\sum_1^{20} X_i>15)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
Sum of independent Poisson variates is itself a Poisson variate, so you need to estimate the cumulative distribution function of a Poisson r.v. with mean $20$. Which is essentially bounding the partial sum of the exponential series... you should get $\approx 0.84$

Comment: Does exist other random variables that fulfill that?

Comment: Sure. Works for normal variates too.

Comment: With the same properties? (mean= sum of the means)

Comment: Yes. Variance is sum of their variances too..